# Cakephp: How to query over 2 tables without a join

Tags: model, find, relation, cakephp-2.1

I am on my Model named "**Objekt**" and it has this relations:

```
var ??? = array(
        'ObjektArtenInternet' => array(
            'className' => 'ObjektArtenInternet',
            'foreignKey' => 'OBI_ID',
            //'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => 'OBI_SORTIERUNG',
            //'order' => ''
        )
    );
```

What I want to do now is this statement:

> SELECT DISTINCT detailobjekt.OBI_ID, OBI_UET_BESCHREIBUNG,
>   OBI_SORTIERUNG FROM detailobjekt, objektarten_internet WHERE
>   detailobjekt.OBI_ID = objektarten_internet.OBI_ID

But I can't figure out how to set the right relation in order to do this select.
With `$belongsTo or $hasOne` I always get a join which I don't need in this case, I simple want to query over 2 tables like in the example above.

How can I do that?
Please help me out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP does not have ORM support for this kind of query. No relationship you set will write a query like this. You have one of two options.

1- User the ORM and allow the JOIN to occur based on the relationship.

2- Write your own query using $this->Model->query();

You will have to weigh the advantages/disadvantages of either option. But why do you not want to do the JOIN? What's wrong with allowing the join?

Besides, MySQL is doing the equivalent of an INNER JOIN on your query anyway. This query is syntactically the same as yours:

```
SELECT *
FROM <firstTable> a INNER JOIN <anotherTable> b
ON a.<someColumn> = b.<anotherColumn>
```